# How to call constructor from templated baseclass

Tags: c++, templates

I have a library with classes I'm using. In my project, I have created a template, so that I can derive from a specialized class, but with my own methods included. Now I have the problem, that I can not call the constructor, which is different for each class I want to use.

I have created a sample project, which demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class Window
{
public:
    Window(int id)
    : m_id(id)
    {
    }

    void printId(void)
    {
        std::cout << "ID:" << m_id << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int m_id;
};

class TextCtrl
: public Window
{
public:
    TextCtrl(int id, Window *parent, int style, const char *value)
    : Window(id)
    , m_parent(parent)
    , m_style(style)
    , m_value(value)
    {
    }

    void printValue(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Style: " << m_style << " Value:" << m_value << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Window *m_parent;
    int m_style;
    const char *m_value;
};

class DateCtrl
: public Window
{
public:
    DateCtrl(int id, Window *parent, uint64_t date, const char *format)
    : Window(id)
    , m_parent(parent)
    , m_date(date)
    , m_format(format)
    {
    }

private:
    Window *m_parent;
    uint64_t m_date;
    const char *m_format;
};

template<typename T>
class Document
: public T
{
public:
    Document(){}
    virtual ~Document(){}

    void serialize(void)
    {
    }

    void deserialize(void)
    {
    }

    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Window, T>::value, "Document must derive from Window");
};

class TextDocument
: public Document<TextCtrl>
{
public:
    TextDocument(int id, Window *parent, int style, const char *value)
    : TextCtrl(id, parent, style, value)
    {
    }
};

class DateDocument
: public Document<DateCtrl>
{
public:
    DateDocument(int id, Window *parent, uint64_t date, const char *format)
    : DateCtrl(id, parent, date, format)
    {
    }
};

class FrameWindow
: public Window
{
public:
    FrameWindow(int id, const char *title)
    : Window(id)
    , m_title(title)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    void addDocument(Document<T> *document)
    {
        std::cout << "Title: " << m_title << std::endl;
        document->printId();
    }

private:
    const char *m_title;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FrameWindow f(1, "title");

    TextDocument(1, &f, 2, "value");
    DateDocument(2, &f, 213412, "YYMM");

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> testproject.cpp(85): error C2614: 'TextDocument': illegal member initialization: 'TextCtrl' is not a base or member

> testproject.cpp(95): error C2614: 'DateDocument': illegal member initialization: 'DateCtrl' is not a base or member

Comment: Why is `Document` template?

Comment: Indeed, this init-syntax is reserved for base classes or members, which they are not.

Comment: Because I need to add the controls to other objects, which require a window class. The other option I see is to add a getter, which gives me the window, but then I need to store the document pointer somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the direct base class, you can't bypass `Document` and directly initialize `TextCtrl`.

The problem is, `Document<T>` has a no-arg constructor, but inherits from `T` which have no such constructor. Hence `Document<T>` can never be instantiated.

You can introduce inherited constructors into scope, then initialize `Document` with the desired arguments.

```
template<typename T>
class Document
: public T
{
public:
    using T::T; // <-- bring T's constructors T into scope
    . . .
```

And then

```
class TextDocument
: public Document<TextCtrl>
{
public:
    TextDocument(int id, Window *parent, int style, const char *value)
    : Document(id, parent, style, value)
    {
    }
};
```

---

P.S. Having virtual members (and a virtual destructor) in a template rarely makes sense. `Document` probably shouldn't be a template, or you won't be able to treat a collection of `Document`s homogeneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialize direct base classes like that. Why is `Document` even a template anyway? It seems like you want it to be kind of an itnerface. Here's what I'd do:

```
class Document
{
public:
    Document() = default;
    virtual ~Document() = default;

    virtual void serialize(void) = 0; // or not virtual, doesn't matter

    virtual void deserialize(void) = 0;
};

class TextDocument : public TextCtrl, public Document {
    // ...
}
```

Then your initialization syntax will work.